# I deleted an app and the database was deleted too, is there a way to recover?

Tags: heroku

I had a database that I was using for two applications, when I deleted one that I no longer used, it deleted the database together, is there a way to recover?

Comment: You could try data recovery tools as the data should still be there, but marked as "allowed to be overwritten". I'm talking about actual bytes on the filesystem though, not through the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Was your second app using manually added credentials to access the database, or did you use Heroku's "Attach Database" option to link to it?

When deleting an app on Heroku, all associated resources that were created within that app will also be deleted. If Heroku was made aware another app was attached to it (via "Attach Database") then it ought to have shown a warning.

Either way, if the database no longer shows in your [data dashboard](https://data.heroku.com/) then it has been removed. Contact Heroku support to see if they keep deleted databases a short time before permanent deletion...

In future, it's worth occasionally using Heroku's "Create Manual Backup" option for databases (you can find it in the "Durability" tab for each database) and downloading a copy to keep safe. (And definitely do a backup again before deleting anything, I always find that a nerve wracking time! ;)